# Flask app not loading any css file from my project

Tags: html, css, flask

I recently started learning Flask and everythings went well until one point.

So, my project is structured this way:

FlaskApp Folder, which contains : Templates(a folder which contains: index.html , layout.html and styles(folder) and javascript(also folder) and application.py.

I included my css in the layout.html (layout.css and bootstrap.css) after the title tag like this:"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/bootstrap.css">
```

And at the bottom, before the  i added the javascript file of the bootstrap:

```
<script src="javascript/boostrap.js"></script>
```

After all of this, i added some html into the index.html from the bootstrap documentation page, such as alert messages...

And there is no CSS applied.(I mention that i've restarted the Flask App).

PS: i added a:

```
 body{ background-color: red; }
```

to the layout.css and it's still not working.

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

This is strictly for development only.

So, you need to have two directories under your app, those are: `static` and `templates`. The `*.html` files are usually palced under `templates` and `*.js` and `*.css` files are placed under `static`.

So your app structure might be something like:

```
app
├── app.py
├── static
│   ├── base.css
│   ├── base.js
│   └── index
│       ├── index.css
│       └── index.js
└── templates
    └── index.html
```

Now, lets move onto how to link these.

In your HTML file, replace the current `<link>` and `<script>` tags with something like this:

For CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href= {{ url_for("static",filename="index/index.css") }} >
```

For JS:

```
<script src= {{ url_for("static",filename="index/index.js") }} ></script>
```

And finally, ensure your python's route returns the appropriate `html` page. Simplest is to use `render_template` function.

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: Okay, could you please mark the answer as solved then.